# xsl-fo different header for first page of document, not each chapter

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using XSL-fo to output from DITA bookmaps to PDF, and I want a unique header that appears on the first page of the document, but not on the first page of every chapter. I've tried  using the page-position attribute of the conditional-page-master-reference element, but this results in my custom header appearing on the first page of every chapter, whereas I want the custom header to appear only a single time, on the first page of the document, with another header appearing on every other page of the document, irrespective of chapter boundaries.

Comment: by first page of document, do you mean the very first page output or the first page of the page sequence?

Comment: First page of output, I guess. The end result is a PDF document with one header on the first page of the document, and a different header on every other page.

Comment: If its a first page of the output, then the first page should be on its own page sequence.

Comment: I've seen many examples of having a separate cover or title page, which has its own sequence, but instead of an entire title page, I want the title of the book to appear one time on the first page within what would normally be considered a header, and on that first page also starts the flow of regular text. I haven't been able to find any examples of that approach.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use page-sequence-master

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="recto-verso-document">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="odd" master-reference="page-odd" blank-or-not-blank="not-blank"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="not-blank" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first" master-reference="last-page-odd"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="not-blank" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest" master-reference="last-page-even"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="even" master-reference="page-even" blank-or-not-blank="not-blank"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

Then for each conditional-page-master-reference, define your simple-page-master for each one:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page-odd" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-left="1.0in" margin-right="0.5in">
        <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="0.80in" margin-bottom=".5in" overflow="auto"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before-first" extent="1in"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="0.6in"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-odd" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-left="1.0in" margin-right="0.5in">
        <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="0.80in" margin-bottom=".5in" overflow="auto"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="1in"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="0.6in"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

Then in your page sequence define your regions for each region-name. For example:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
        <fo:block>do something for your header</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>


 <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block>do something for your header</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
```

Without seeing your FO, this is the best I can offer in terms of how to resolve your problem

Comment: Your example is cut off on the right hand side, so I can't see all of it.

Comment: I see it. There is a scroll bar?

Comment: If you are using a Mac, the scrollbar might be invisible. (It's there though). For example, try to move two fingers to the lext on the mouse pad.

Comment: I am using a Mac, and now I see how to scroll. Thanks.

Comment: So this example is essentially what I'm using right now, but the result is that my custom header appears on the first page of each chapter, rather than only one time at the beginning of the entire document.

Comment: @rraleigh without seeing a small snippet of the relevant FO, I can't help you. Perhaps you can post the parts of the FO that are causing the issue.

Comment: @rraleigh, create a second `fo:page-sequence-master` which does not have the different header for first page, and use that for latter chapters.